# Multi-term in Emacs under Cygwin doesn't correctly identify terminal type?

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I've installed Cygwin on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. After a `rebaseall`, Cygwin works nicely. However, I use multi-term in my default Emacs setup, and multi-term doesn't seem to like Cygwin at all.

It looks as though multi-term isn't correctly identifying the terminal type. It's writing what I think are control characters visibly in the buffer, and simple things like `clear` and linefeeds don't work.

Here's what it looks like at startup:

[image: Multi-term in Emacs under Cygwin]

Is there a way of getting this working? I'm very used to having multiple terminals available in Emacs on Linux and would hate to lose this functionality under Cygwin.

Comment: Not even a bounty made a difference ... :-(  Still, I'm now developing in RoR on a mix of Mac OS X & Linux so hopefully I'll never be back to Windows ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is resolved by explicitly stating the terminal type. I use multi-term for emacs in cygwin on windows7 x64 with the following lines in my .emacs:

```
(require 'multi-term)
(setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash")  ;; <--- this is what you need
(setq multi-term-dedicated-select-after-open-p t)
(setq multi-term-dedicated-close-back-to-open-buffer-p t)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x t") 'multi-term-dedicated-toggle)
```